# How do I configure OpenWRT/dnsmasq to not do reverese lookups for local IP addresses?

Tags: router, dns, openwrt

OpenWRT does a bunch of "reverse look-ups" for 108.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa, but the host-names for this should be known by OpenWRT as it DHCP assigned the local ip settings for these. I do have another dns but it can't reverse resolve the local ip addresses.

I might be wrong about these being reverse look-ups as the query type is SAO and not PTR, but the queries are made to .in-addr.arpa which is for reverse look-ups.

What config do I need to add to my router?

```
cat /etc/config/dhcp

config dnsmasq
        option domainneeded '1'
        option localise_queries '1'
        option rebind_protection '1'
        option rebind_localhost '1'
        option local '/lan/'
        option domain 'lan'
        option expandhosts '1'
        option authoritative '1'
        option readethers '1'
        option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
        option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.d/resolv.conf.auto'
        option localservice '1'
        option ednspacket_max '1232'
        list server '192.168.1.173'

config dhcp 'lan'
        option interface 'lan'
        option start '100'
        option limit '150'
        option leasetime '12h'
        option dhcpv4 'server'
        option dhcpv6 'server'
        option ra 'server'
        list ra_flags 'managed-config'
        list ra_flags 'other-config'
        list dhcp_option '6,192.168.1.173'

config dhcp 'wan'
        option interface 'wan'
        option ignore '1'
        list ra_flags 'none'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
        option maindhcp '0'
        option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
        option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
        option loglevel '4'
```

[image: pi-hole: openWRT making a query for a local address]